# A function to search from a list with two different ways

Tags: python

I'm kind of new to python. So, I wonder which method is better to use in a function to find an element in a list.

First:

```
def search_binary(xs,target):
    count = 0
    for i in xs:
        if i == target:
            return count
            count = count +1
        else:
            count = count +1
            continue
    return -1
```

Second:

```
def search_binary(xs, target):
    lb = 0
    ub = len(xs)
    while True:
        if lb == ub:   
           return -1

        mid_index = (lb + ub) // 2

        item_at_mid = xs[mid_index]


        if item_at_mid == target:
            return mid_index      
        if item_at_mid < target:
            lb = mid_index + 1    
        else:
            ub = mid_index
```

Comment: is the list sorted?  if not the answer is neither :)

Comment: and if you're doing a binary search, you should be using the `bisect` module.

Answer (score 1):

if list is not sorted or small using linear search like the first makes sense, however it should be done like this:

```
# linear search O(n)
xs.index(target)
```

if list is sorted and large you should use a binary search like the second, however it would be better to do it using [bisect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) like this:

```
# binary search O(log n)
from bisect import bisect_left
def search_binary(xs, target):
    i = bisect_left(xs, target)
    if i != len(xs) and xs[i] == target:
        return i
    raise ValueError
```

Answer (score 0):

The second,

this isn't really specific to Python though, the first operates in O(n) time, the second is binary search and operates in O(log(n)) time